# Process.StandardOutput.Readline() hangs on Mono but not on .NET

Tags: python, mono, stdout, stdin

I am trying to have a C# program running on Mono (on Ubuntu) invoke a python script, send data to its stdin, and read data back from its stdout.  The test code below captures the essential idea:

```
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("python");
startInfo.Arguments = "./hello.py";
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

var p = Process.Start(startInfo);
if(p.HasExited)
    return;

p.StandardInput.WriteLine("Bob");
var result = p.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Result: {0}", result);
```

The code for hello.py is simply:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
line = raw_input()
while len(line) > 0:
    print("Hello " + line)
    line = raw_input()
```

When I execute this test code on .NET/Windows, the test above works as expected, returning the result "Hello Bob".  But on Mono/Linux the C# program hangs on the call to `p.StandardOutput.ReadLine();`.  Any idea why it doesn't work on Mono/Linux, and what I need to change to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question... Turns out this has nothing to do with Mono or Linux, but rather the behaviour of Python on Windows vs Linux.  To get it working on Linux required invoking Python with the -u flag (unbuffered output), so that the printed data is actually flushed to stdout.  Thanks to "weeble" on the Mono mailing list for the tip!